# Code-behind hangs when data binding Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm working on a web form in ASP.NET 4, and I need to display a long list of entries in a table based on a selection made in a drop down list. I have the following ASPX and code-behind:

```
<form method="post" runat="server" >
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="mScriptManager"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlLocalizationInfo" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="selectLanguage">
                <p>Pick language
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddllanguage" runat="server" OnTextChanged="SelectLanguage" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="languageTable">
        <asp:Repeater id="repTable" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="AddTableData" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
            Language: 
            <asp:Label ID="lbllanguageTable" runat="server" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltableNameLocalization" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfnameLocalization" runat="server" Value='<%#((Localization)Container.DataItem).Id %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txttableValueLocalization" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button ID="btnupdateLocalization" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateLocalization" Text="Save" />           
            </div>                
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

---

```
public void SelectLanguage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lang = ddllanguage.SelectedValue;
    if (ddllanguage.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        repTable.DataSource = Data.GetAllLocalizations(lang);
        repTable.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The call `GetAllLocalizations` returns an ArrayList with database entities that are later used to populate the Repeater table. However, the `DataBind` function hangs upon calling, so the entire form stops working whenever the drop down list is changed. If the data binding is done on page load and not in an event handler, it works fine. I have another, older page that uses this same method though (data bind in event handler of a drop down list) and it works without a hitch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you call `OnItemDataBound`, I would check this event, there is possibly that there is some process that takes time to finish or may be in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! It seemed that there was an exception occurring in the event handler for OnItemDataBound, and it wasn't showing in any way. I just assumed that the DataBind call was hanging since control immediately returned to the browser during debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Jekom to an extent.

Also can you not just display the database results directly? why are they being passed into an array first?

I find when working with repeaters or any data display is to create stored procedures or functions in SQL and allow the server to do the work.

The reason you may have difficulty the way you are doing it is you are asking the client to work out all the information and you say there is a vast array of data to go through.

Its hard to be more specific without more information